# Unchecked runtime.lastError - received while retrieving data using "chrome.storage.local.get" in background.js and passing it to popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to retrieve data from the **localStorage** inside **background.js** and pass it to **popup.js**, but receiving the below error,

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

> Note: the below snippet prints the **localStorage** to the console of *background.js*
> `chrome.storage.local.get(["dsr_db"], function (result) { console.log(result); });`

**popup.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="display-db">
    Displaye DB
</button>
```

**popup.js**

```
let display_db = document.getElementById("display-db");

display_db.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "display-db"}, function(response) {
    alert(response.message);
  });
});
```

**backgroun.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.greeting == "display-db") {
    chrome.storage.local.get(["dsr_db"], function (result) {
      sendResponse({ message: result });
    });
  }
});
```

---

Any workaround which could be made inside **background.js** to make the connection long enough and pass the *localStorage* object to **popup.js**??

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the docs, (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/) adding `return true` to the `onMessage` event handler will make the response asynchronous.

Comment: @HK - Guess this would be the expected code : `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.greeting == "display-db") {
    sendResponse({ message: db });
    return true;
  }
});
`
I know I'm wrong here, cuz getting the same error >Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

Comment: Tried inside the **try**, **catch** block to assign the value to localStorage. It worked !

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you. Just in case anyone else comes here. The `return true` should be after the closing bracket of the if statement.

Comment: Simply read the storage in the popup, there's no need for the background script here.